# Setting Kubernetes Nodes for Bare Metal Deployment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes

I'm consider using `kubeadm` or `Conjure-Up` for a bare metal deployment. I'm not sure how to set a cluster since it requires a Master and Worker Node. If I just have a single Linux machine, could the worker and master node be the same? If so, what's the best way to do that.

For `kubeadm` I know that I can run `kubeadm init` to set the Master Node and then use `kudeadm join <token>` on subsequent machines to set as the Worker Node but I'm not sure if this is advisable.

For Conjure-Up, I just created the deployment using the `kubernetes core` spell and it created a kubernetes worker and master but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go. Another option I heard is using MAAS but I don't have much experience with it.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in the [user manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) including `kubeadm init` and you will end up with a 1 node running as master. You do not have to add nodes with `kubeadm join` so just skip *(4/4) Joining your nodes*. Do not execute `kubeadm join` on your master.

To enable normal scheduling on the master you will have to remove the `dedicated=master:NoSchedule` *taint* from it with this command:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all dedicated-
```